# Determining if a set of rate limits were breached per entity ID in a set of rows

Tags: mysql

I can do this in the application layer, but I'm wondering if this is possible in MySQL.

Suppose we have a table `event_history`

```
entity_id INT 
event_ts INT    # Unix timestamp.
event_cost INT        # Not all events cost the same towards the rate limit.
# And some other columns.
```

And a table `rate_limit_rules`

```
time_interval INT    # Number of seconds
rate_limit INT  # Upper limit of SUM(event_history.cost) in the interval per entity.
```

Is there a way to determine if any of the `rate_limit_rules` were violated by any of the `entity_id`?  And if so, is there a way to determine specifically which rules were broken by which entities?

EDIT

Example data set:

```
SELECT * FROM event_history;
+-----------+----------+------------+
| entity_id | event_ts | event_cost |
+-----------+----------+------------+
|         1 |        0 |        600 |
|         1 |        5 |        200 |
|         1 |        9 |       1100 |
|         1 |       14 |        800 |
|         2 |       10 |        500 |
|         2 |       12 |        400 |
|         2 |       25 |         50 |
|         3 |       21 |        100 |
|         4 |       30 |         90 |
+-----------+----------+------------+

SELECT * FROM rate_limit_rules;
+---------------+------------+
| time_interval | rate_limit |
+---------------+------------+
|             1 |        600 |
|            10 |        800 |
+---------------+------------+
```

## output

```
entity_id, time_interval, event_ts_triggered_at, interval_cost_sum
        1,             1,                     0,               600
        1,             1,                     9,              1100
        1,             1,                    14,               800
        1,             10,                    5,               800
        1,             10,                    9,              1900
        2,             10,                   12,               900
```

To create the tables with those seed data:

```
# event_history
CREATE TABLE `event_history` (
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_ts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`event_ts`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `event_history` (`entity_id`, `event_ts`, `event_cost`) VALUES
('1', '0', '600'),
('1', '5', '200'),
('1', '9', '1100'),
('1', '14', '800'),
('2', '10', '500'),
('2', '12', '400'),
('2', '25', '50'),
('3', '21', '100'),
('4', '30', '90');

# rate_limit_rules
CREATE TABLE `rate_limit_rules` (
  `time_interval` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate_limit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time_interval`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `rate_limit_rules` (`time_interval`, `rate_limit`) VALUES
('1', '600'),
('10', '800');
```

Obviously I could solve this in the application layer by iterating over every event in the event history, and then for that event, per rate limit rule take the interval and run a query to find `SUM(event_cost)` in the interval up to that event.

Compare that sum against the rate limit in the rule, and if it breaches, that's a breach.  This would involve quite a horrifically large number of queries being run as the data set grows.

That can be trivially mitigated by maintaining a cursor of the last event parsed (where the cursor uses a nondecreasing indexed column of some kind, such as an autoincrementing primary key), but I wonder if this can be done in a better way in MySQL, without the help of the application layer.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Edited with an example data set and output.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to come up with a query in MySQL, although tbh at the moment I have literally no idea where to start for doing such a query outside of the application layer (where I'd end up doing multiple queries, one per rate limit interval per event).  Tbh doing this in pure MySQL is quite beyond me but maybe with some more time I can come up with something haha.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I had the data in CSV format, let me update that with INSERTs instead.

Comment: this must be programmed, so try this in a stored procedure and there is the chance to build it like a pivot table, but that would make it not prettier than the stored procedure

Comment: Hmm I'll look up how to do this in a stored procedure.  Given that the code to do this in the application layer is rather straightforward (if a bit inefficient in the number of queries executed), would you rather put it in a stored procedure vs in the application, for the sake of clarity in the codebase?  The script running this is a background script that has no particular realtime demands, if that matters.

Comment: What is time_interval 2?

Comment: That is a horrific typo that was supposed to be 10 haha.

Comment: Im still struggling to understand how event_ts relates to time_interval (assuming it does)

Comment: event_ts is a generic unix timestamp.  time_interval is the number of seconds in the defined interval.  So, if the rate limit uses a time_interval of 10 seconds, that means for any given event, the sum of all costs for all events attached to that event's entity (such a user ID) in the 10 seconds prior to and including that event cannot exceed the defined rate limit, or else we include it in the result set as a rate limit breaker.

Comment: I've gone ahead and implemented it in the application layer.  It processes about 400 events per second, which actually for the events involved works fine, it just doesn't look so pretty.